# Contact vs Subscribers in BUs

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

I recently found I have avg. 6m contacts (as per contact report) and 2m subscribers  (per all subsc) in my SFMC account. I am confused I thought subscribers (if not equal) will be always greater than contacts.

And this spike happen in last month, is their a way to find out which BU and data extension has import such high number of records in past month? Any report is  available or queering data views? I came across SFMC does not offer list of contacts so hard to start investigating?

Any idea?

Comment: Are you connected to a live Salesforce org? If yes are people running tests there and creating/deleting contacts?

Comment: Good call @Rufenstein, maybe worth connecting SFDC team to find out.

Answer (score 2):

The help page '[Contact Definition and Count Determination](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5)' does a great job breaking this down. All subscribers are contacts but not all contacts are subscribers. Subscribers are contacts that are belong to a channel (email/sms/push/ott)

Best guess is this spike has come from synchronized data extensions.

This help article '[Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&type=1&mode=1)' will assist in finding/deleting contacts

Comment: Thanks @EazyE, I already have checked the Contact def. count link. I start investigating from Sync DEs as I was also guessing it's maybe Sync but honestly I didn't find anything suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you started using Mobile Push or Mobile Connect? This could also affect the number of Contacts, especially if the matching to Subscribers is not done correctly.